# What's the difference between Ubuntu for free and the Official CD for $5?

Tags: live-cd, cd, canonical

What's the difference between Ubuntu 12.04 LTS for free and the Official CD of Ubuntu for $5? I didn't know the difference.

Answer (score 25):

There's no difference. The CD is just an annual thing they do for people with slow connections and to raise funds for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 21):

They charge the cost for the CD/DVD, maybe shipping & handling and the seconds it takes to burn it. This helps in several key points:

- Helps users with very slow connection, limited bandwidth or no connection at all get the CD/DVD. This are the 3 types of users that actually benefit more from this.
- Helps raise funds for multiple causes
- The buyer gets a cool printed CD with the Ubuntu version, Ubuntu logo and a neat Ubuntu cover.
- The buyer also gets several stickers that look great on the PC/Laptop.

For the 12.04 for example you would get a box cover like this:

[image]

And the CD Cover like this:

[image]

In the case of Ubuntu, they charge 5$ for a pack of 5CDs + S&H. Is it worth it, most definitely yeah!. I mean you are getting all that for a little more than 5$.

The only downside is that you'll turn into my dad. He has a collection of all Ubuntu / Xubuntu / Lubuntu / Kubuntu / Edubuntu... CDs since it came out. And I MEAN a collection that he doesn't even take out of the cover box. I mean do you know how many versions of Ubuntu there are and types of flavors. It almost looks like a music collection if you look at it from the side.

Comment: Can you post a photo of that collection? Would be fun to see that :)

Comment: Let me ask hehe.

Comment: @Lipis Hi, could not find the rest of the CD/DVD. My father had them but I moved to Costa Rica looking for work and did not bring the CD/DVD with me. He told me a couple of days ago that he gave them away to several friends and he is teaching older friends to use Ubuntu.

Answer (score 17):

There is no difference.  Both are the same.  But if you like to have the official CD, for keepsake, you can do so.  Plus if you have a slow connection, or planning bulk deployment, getting the CD would be an idea.

> The price is $5 for a pack of 5, so you can pass it on.  Or you can
>   download it, and make your own CD, and pass it on.<sup>1</sup>

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)</sup>

To buy Ubuntu CD:

[Click Here](http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=976)

Download Link for Ubuntu CD:

[Click Here](http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=976)

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference the users who find it difficult to download can buy the CD for $5. You are free to clone the disk and distribute among your friends.